# Understand JS .match() work

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi i have next string and regexp:

```
"Hello many 2014 (12) and another (88)".match(/\((\d+)\)/g)
```

Why return value is ["(12)", "(88)"] instead of [12, 88] ?
I need a second option.

Comment: It is the behavior of the `match` function.

Comment: Fix the title of your post. The regexp is working fine. What is not working is your understanding of how `match` works.

Comment: `.match()` returns all the matches of the entire regexp, not just the capture group.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
\d+(?=\))
```

You can try this.This should work for you.

If you have strings like `abc (def 234) (45)` Then use `\((\d+)\)` and grab `group 1`.

Comment: It will not work correctly for the input string `abc (def 234) (45)`

Comment: OP's intention seems to be to extract 45 out of the example string I gave above and leave 234 alone.

Comment: It is doesn't work for me ["(12", "(88"] = "Hello many 2014 (12) and another (88)".match(/\(\d+(?=\))/g)

Comment: @IlyaManyahin `\d+(?=\))` you have use soething different